# Web Config Connection Setting

Tags: asp.net

I heve designed a website in which every pages are given connection with SQL server by writing the codes in each page....Can anybody helps me out to do this job only in the web config file at once...

Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try this:

in web config:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add 
    name="NorthwindConnectionString" 
    connectionString="Data Source=serverName;Initial 
    Catalog=Northwind;Persist Security Info=True;User 
    ID=userName;Password=password"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
  />
</connectionStrings>
```

to read in .cs page

```
System.Configuration.Configuration rootWebConfig =
                System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/MyWebSiteRoot");
            System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettings connString;
            if (rootWebConfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings.Count > 0)
            {
                connString =
                    rootWebConfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["NorthwindConnectionString"];
                if (connString != null)
                    Console.WriteLine("Northwind connection string = \"{0}\"",
                        connString.ConnectionString);
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("No Northwind connection string");
            }
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178411.aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
<connectionStrings>  
        <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(local); 
        Initial Catalog=DbName; Integrated Security=True" 
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 1):

In web.config file

```
    <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="server=(local); 
database=DbName; uid=*username*; password=*password*;" 
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Answer (score 0):

`<connectionStrings>
    <add name="SourceNet_R01ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=10.134.72.61;Initial Catalog=SourceNet_R01;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="SourceNet_R01ConnectionString1" connectionString="Data Source=10.134.72.61;Initial Catalog=SourceNet_R01;User ID=dev;Password=vcel92" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>`

For retrieving can use 
`ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[1].ConnectionString`